# How to add URL parameters in YouTube Android API?

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api

I am using `YouTube API` inside my Android app.Below is the code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.graphs.youtubeapitext;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;
    private YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
//        youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager()
//                .findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
//        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo("fhWaJi1Hsfo"); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String error = String.format(getString(R.string.player_error), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    protected Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return youTubeView;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <!--<fragment-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"-->
        <!--android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I enable the `modestbranding` to 1 ? [modestbranding](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#modestbranding) is a parameter you can use in Youtube URL to customize the player.

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Comment: @HiteshDanidhariya: Well, it is impossible with the Android API